# Improve sprites rendering performance?

Tags: python, pygame, sdl, sdl-2, pysdl2

I'm looking for a way how to improve performance of PySDL2 rendering large amount of big sprites. Bellow is my attempt, trying to use hardware rendering as much as possible:

```
import sdl2.ext as sdl2ext, sdl2
import sys
from random import randint

def run():
    sdl2ext.init()
    disp_mode = sdl2.video.SDL_DisplayMode()
    sdl2.SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode(0, disp_mode)
    window = sdl2ext.Window('pysdl2 benchmark', size=(disp_mode.w, disp_mode.h),
            flags=sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP)
    window_w, window_h = window.size
    window.show()

    renderer = sdl2ext.Renderer(window)
    factory = sdl2ext.SpriteFactory(sprite_type=sdl2ext.TEXTURE,
            renderer=renderer)
    spr_image = sdl2ext.image.load_image('big_sprite.png')
    sprites = [factory.from_surface(spr_image) for _ in xrange(100)]
    for spr in sprites:
        spr.position = randint(0,160), randint(0,90)
        spr.w, spr.h = spr.size
        spr.dx = randint(1,16); spr.dy = randint(1,16)
    renderer_spr = sdl2.ext.TextureSpriteRenderSystem(renderer)

    running = True
    while running:
        events = sdl2ext.get_events()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
                running = False
                break
        renderer.clear(COLOR_CARMINE)    # instance of sdl2ext.Color
        renderer_spr.render(sprites)
        renderer.present()
        # Updating sprites positions
        for spr in sprites:
            if spr.x + spr.w + spr.dx > window_w or \
                    spr.x + spr.dx < 0:
                        spr.dx = -spr.dx
            if spr.y + spr.h + spr.dy > window_h or \
                    spr.y + spr.dy < 0:
                        spr.dy = -spr.dy
            spr.x += spr.dx
            spr.y += spr.dy
        #window.refresh()
    sdl2ext.quit()
    return 0
```

As the documentation to PySDL2 is rather sparse, I'm curious if I did possibly missed something important and written code is somehow suboptimal.

Comment: How about posting at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? You could try [pyopengl](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/). Here's a [tutorial](http://www.hivestream.de/python-3-and-opengl-woes.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Some quick performance advice**

- You should first tell us what is the current performance of this example. Anything above 60 fps is fine.
- Use a profiler to find bottlenecks.
- Be mindful of the fact that python loops are inherently slow. You should find a way to provide type information and/or remove bound checks
- Libraries like numpy can help

**More details**

In the kivy framework we use Cython (compiling python to C where it makes sense). Now, I don't know the specifics of what you're trying to do, so take it for what it's worth. Python loops are slow, especially if you are using a game loop to update sprites.

I once wrote a shmup, and faced the same problem. Best performance was obtained by cythonizing the project (30% flat gain). Then I tried to (strongly) type every thing I could (cython again), then I optimized the python loops while using the profiler. You are already deleting sprites going off-screen, (but you should check it works correctly), be mindful of the cost of object creation/garbage collection.